# Python mysql cursor.execute() have issues?

Tags: python, mysql, cursor

I have some trouble getting data from my `MySQL` db using `Python3.4.`

This is my code :

```
connection = pymysql.connect(host='localhost',
                             user='root',
                             password=MY_PASSWD,
                             db=MY_DB,
                             charset='utf8',
                             cursorclass=pymysql.cursors.DictCursor)

with connection.cursor() as cursor:
    # it doens't works works
    table_name = 'id_pw'
    key_name = 'url'
    key_value = 'naver.com'
    sql = "SELECT * FROM %s WHERE %s=\'%s\'"
    cursor.execute(sql, (table_name, key_name, key_value))

    # it works.
    sql = "SELECT * FROM id_pw WHERE url=\'naver.com\'"
    cursor.execute(sql)
```

Could you tell me what is wrong? I have no idea what I missed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You *cannot parameterize table or column names*, use string formatting for that and query parameters for everything else:

```
sql = "SELECT * FROM {table} WHERE {column} = %s".format(table=table_name, column=key_name)
cursor.execute(sql, (key_value, ))
```

Note that you also don't need the quotes around the placeholder - the database driver would handle that automagically.

And, as another note, make sure you either trust where the `table_name` and `key_name` are coming from, or validate/escape them. Make sure your code is not vulnerable to SQL injections because of the string formatting we are introducing.